# Can a mongoose document value be a function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For the sake of argument, let's take this schema:

```
const ImaginarySchema = new Schema ({
    Name: String,
    Age: Number,
    Weight: Number, 
    Value: Number, 
    });
```

In this Schema, the way value is calculated is represented by the following function:

```
function calculateValue(age, weight) {
    value = Age*Weight; 
};
```

Given that everyday the age increases by one, this value is of course regularly changing and therefore needs to be calculated with a function automatically.

What is the best way to implement this and where should it be placed in the application?

---

My attempts:

---

Firstly, I wanted to try the following syntax, but according to the [mongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) it is not advisable to store application logic on the server so saving this function in server.js doesn't seem to be the best idea, and that is assuming that this kind of syntax is even possible.

```
const ImaginarySchema = new Schema ({
    Name: String,
    AgeinDays: Number,
    Weight: Number, 
    Value: calculateValue(), 
    });
```

Secondly I was looking at something like below but again I was unclear at whether this should be in the model file, and if it is in the model file, then how could this be run regularly.

```
.pre('save'), function(next){
function calculateValue(age, weight) {
   value = Age*Weight; 
 next(); 
 };
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can't you just calculate that on the fly when you need it?

Comment: Perhaps I could do actually, is that common practice? I will have a significant number of documents in the collection so run time could be an issue?

Comment: When do you need the value? And how many values do you need all the time?

Comment: I need to display all entries where value > x on a given page. So whenever the user visits this page this would have to be calculated. I assumed the best would be to do a get request and read the values rather than update them and then read them, because in my application there are several values which contribute to this final value which is compared to x.

Comment: Multiplication on the client side is probably the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are searching for the elusive Mongoose statics:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics

Statics create an artificial method that resolves to what you would like it to be.

If that is not what you are searching for, look below it, there are Query Helpers that might suit your needs.

If that is still not what you are searching for, look below it, there are Virtuals that I think most closely matches your description.

---

Bar the above, I would not recommend you go about updating your data source (database) to store dynamic values given the same static inputs. I would recommend you have a model layer (that defines the schema and the statics / helpers associated with the schema) and use that instead to calculate your values.

Comment: Virtuals were exactly what I was after, they let me code functions into the DB which can be easily called, brilliant, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mongoose SchemaTypes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html), a document cannot be a function.
Valid types include:

- String
- Number
- Date
- Buffer
- Boolean
- Mixed
- ObjectId
- Array
- Decimal128
- Map